# bind function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the html I am using

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center permissions-submit">
          <button class="btn btn-primary ">Set Permissions</button>
 </div>
//remove extra ending div
```

Now I have written a method named bindEvents which would do the following

```
 bindEvents : function(){
        this.$elSubmit = $('.permissions-submit');
        this.$elSubmitButton = this.$elSubmit.find('button');
        console.log('submit',this.$elSubmitButton);
        this.$elSubmitButton.on('click',this.permissionsSubmit.bind(this));
    }
```

The issue is that,nothing happens on the button click. It is supposed to call the method "permissionsSubmit".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bauxkznt/1/ - seems fine.. how is `bindEvents` called

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes,it was working for me in fiddle too. But in my page which Iam working it is not. Any ideas for debugging?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try this as it's mentioned on jQuery API.

```
 $( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
        //Do your work here
  });
```